# replace de caracteres especiales usando expresión regular

Tags: regex

Estoy intentado reemplazar tres caracteres (>>>) por una marca en una cadena HTML en memoria usando una expresión regular en jscript.
He hecho:

```
texto = texto.replace(/&gt;&gt;&gt;(.*$)/g, '<span class="prm_">&gt;&gt;&gt;</span>$1')
```

Sin resultado

He cambiado, más que nada por probar, a:

```
texto = texto.replace(/>>>(.*$)/g, '<span class="prm_">&gt;&gt;&gt;</span>$1')
```

Que estoy haciendo mal?

El texto puede ser todo lo grande que se quiera y los tres caracteres (>>>) aparecerán en cualquier parte, e incluso varias veces a lo largo del texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la verdad es que no entiendo muy bien la pregunta JL, podrías explicarlo de una manera distinta por favor, puede que te ayude otra persona, hice lo del remplazo y me funciona. Pero no se si te ayudará exactamente esto.

```
p1 = '&gt;&gt;&gt;'
const regex1 = /&gt;&gt;&gt;/g
console.log(p1.replace(regex1,'<span class="prm_">&gt;&gt;&gt;</span>$1'))

p2 = '>>>'
const regex2 = />>>/g
console.log(p2.replace(regex2,'<span class="prm_">&gt;&gt;&gt;</span>$1'))
```

Comment: Tus cadenas p1 y p2  no son solo esos tres caracteres en mi caso. Tengo un texto sembrado con esos caracteres, y quiero reemplazar todas las ocurrencias que aparezcan. Generalmente aparecen al principio del texto, pero puede darse el caso que estén en otras partes.

Comment: Tenias toda la razón. Solucionado. Me estaba complicando la vida.

    texto = texto.replace(/&gt;&gt;&gt;/g, '<span class="prm_">&gt;&gt;&gt;</span>');

Un sencillo 'replace' con /g para todas las repeticiones.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en `(.*$)`

`$` es el caracter para matchear "fin de línea/string". Debería estar fuera del paréntesis